# wordpress with different domains

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a multi-lingual site. Firstly I created a wordpress website. Then I installed wordpress on another site and changed the table prefix of the second site to the one of the first site. So now these sites are sharing the same database and their addresses are http://academy2.hollywoodpress.biz and http://en.hollywoodpress.biz  . However, http://en.hollywoodpress.biz is not working but http://en.hollywoodpress.biz/wp-admin is working. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please make the question more understandable. Also ask WordPress related question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you change the site and home URL in the database?

Comment: oh yes. sorry.  I changed it again now.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use WordPress multi sites feature.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Thanks but I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make WordPress use somewhat dynamic request hostnames using the following in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

This way WP will set the site and home URL addresses properly for each domain which is used to request a WordPress page. I think `wp-admin` will use the value which is determined in the `wp_options` table (`home` and `siteurl` rows).

If you need to display different content on different domains altogether, then you should consider either multisite or two separate WP installations.

If you're only looking to translate content and are OK with either subdomains (en, de, es, etc.) or subfolders (en, de, es, etc.), consider using localization plugin such as Polylang or WPML.

Comment: On which site hould I add the two lines on wp-config.php?

Comment: I will add:  define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://en.hollywoodpress.biz' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://academy2.hollywoodpress.biz' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);               Should I replace the text of HTTP_HOST with a server name or something?

Comment: I want to use different domains.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. The problem was that I used subdomains for separating domains and they didn't work for WPML. I used a domain and I could finally separate domains.